# Execute method on mongoid scope chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, mongoid

I need to take some random documents using Rails and MongoId. Since I plan to have very large collections I decided to put a 'random' field in each document and to select documents using that field. I wrote the following method in the model:

```
def random(qty)
  if count <= qty
    all
  else
    collection = [ ]
    while collection.size < qty
      collection << where(:random_field.gt => rand).first
    end
    collection
  end
end
```

This function actually works and the collection is filled with *qty* random elements. But as I try to use it like a scope like this:

```
User.students.random(5)
```

I get:

```
undefined method `random' for #<Array:0x0000000bf78748>
```

If instead I try to make the method like a lambda scope I get:

```
undefined method `to_criteria' for #<Array:0x0000000df824f8>
```

Given that I'm not interested in applying any other scopes after the *random* one, how can I use my method in a chain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extending the Mongoid::Criteria class with the following. Don't know if it's the best option. Actually I believe it's quite slow since it executes at least *qty* queries.

I don't know if *not_in* is available for normal ActiveRecord modules. However you can remove the *not_in* part if needed. It's just an optimization to reduce the number of queries.

On collections that have a double (or larger) number of documents than qty, you should have exactly *qty* queries.

```
module Mongoid
  class Criteria

    def random(qty)
      if count <= qty
        all
      else
        res = [ ]
        ids = [ ]
        while res.size < qty
          el = where(:random_field.gt => rand).not_in(id: ids).first

          unless el.nil?
            res << el
            ids << el._id
          end
        end
        res
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Hope you find this useful :)

Comment: Interesting solution. In the past I've used `pluck` to pull out all the id's (which is relatively fast) and then `sample(n)` to take a random sample of the id's. Then `Model.find(ids)` to pull out the random n models.